# Zoom in e Zoom out em CSS3 na mesma animação

Tags: html5, css3

Estou tentando fazer uma animação em CSS3 com zoom in, zoom out e transition em CSS3 + HTML. O que eu quero é que ao passar o mouse sobre a div, a mesma diminua para escala 0.9 e depois aumente para 1.1 na mesma animação.

Segue códigos CSS e HTML:

```css
.abc
{
  margin:1.5em;
  background-color:#ff0;
    border:0;
    width:196px;
    height:210px;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    transition: all 200ms ease-in;
}
.abc:hover
{
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -ms-transform: scale(0.9);   
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);   
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.9);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    transform: scale(0.9);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="abc">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Já que consegui resolver, vou responder minha pergunta para ajudar aos outros.

Segue o código:

```css
  div{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #ff0;
    margin: 1em;
    -webkit-transition: transform .1s;
    transition: transform .1s;
  }

div:hover{
  -webkit-animation: pulse .25s;
  animation: pulse .25s;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
@keyframes pulse {
    0%   {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    }
    50%  {
    -webkit-transform: scale(.8);
    -ms-transform: scale(.8);
    -moz-transform: scale(.8);
    transform: scale(.8);
    }
    100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
    }
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```